Help me understand magic numbers in Chaos Vehicle plugin's torque calculation
I'm trying to understand the logic implemented in the Chaos Vehicle plugin. I need your help with following points:
1. Torque conversion
If I’m not wrong then the brake torque unit is Nm, and converting it to Ncm requires multiply it by 100. But as shown in the code, the brake torque is multiplied by 10000.
UE_5.4\Engine\Plugins\Experimental\ChaosVehiclesPlugin\Source\ChaosVehicles\Private\ChaosWheeledVehicleMovementComponent.cpp


if (PWheel.BrakeEnabled)
{
    float BrakeForce = PWheel.MaxBrakeTorque * ModifiedInputs.BrakeInput;
 
    PWheel.SetBrakeTorque(TorqueMToCm(BrakeForce + EngineBrakingForce), FMath::Abs(EngineBrakingForce) > FMath::Abs(BrakeForce));
}
else
{
    PWheel.SetBrakeTorque(TorqueMToCm(EngineBraking), true);
}

UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Experimental\ChaosVehicles\ChaosVehiclesCore\Public\VehicleUtility.h

FORCEINLINE float TorqueMToCm(float TorqueIn)
{
    return TorqueIn * 10000.0f;
}

2. Force required to stop a wheel
What is the meaning of K? Is it some kind of friction coefficient? Why is the value set to 0.4?
UE_5.4\Engine\Source\Runtime\Experimental\ChaosVehicles\ChaosVehiclesCore\Private\WheelSystem.cpp

void FSimpleWheelSim::Simulate(float DeltaTime)
{
    float K = 0.4f;
    float TractionControlAndABSScaling = 0.98f;
    // how close to perfection is the system working
    if (Braking)
    {
        // whether the velocity is +ve or -ve when we brake we are slowing the vehicle down
        // so force is opposing current direction of travel.
        float ForceRequiredToBringToStop = MassPerWheel * K * (LocalWheelVelocity.X) / DeltaTime;
        FinalLongitudinalForce = AppliedLinearBrakeForce;
    }
}


Is it possible the calculation is being done on squared values? That might explain the 10000 factor, since $1 (Nm)^2 = 10000 (Ncm)^2$. Often game code will work with the square of a vector's magnitude if that's convenient to calculate, and put off the expensive square root operation as long as possible, so maybe that's what they've done here. Posting this as a comment as this is pure speculation, and I don't know anything about this specific implementation.

(1A) Measuring something in Ncm does not make sense. It is maybe a kind of conversion needed for the "PWheel" (PlayerWheel?) Is this a kind of wheel game controller, then maybe a Ncm is needed if the specification demands it.
(1B) As above, *10000 does not make any sense to me, other than this is a magic number to "tweak" something. Like making the overall/global break forces stronger.
(2) K is also just some magic number. It tweaks the formula to account for only about half the mass of a wheel or wheel velocity. I think the effect is, breaking takes a little longer in-game. Maybe this has the apparent effect of less friction, as you suspected.
